# Listing instance attributes with __dict__

Tags: python, dictionary, subclass

Hi I am trying to use composition to create a new class using instances of another class when I try to turn the new object into a dictionary using `__dict__`, it's shows me `<__main__.myobjec object at 0x00000000029CA908>`, not sure am I using the `__dict__` incorrectly though I have heard its related to new classes, any help greatly appreciated.

```
class User:

    def __init__(self, name, job=None):

        self.name = name
        self.job = job


class Customer(User):

    _ID = 100

    def __init__(self, name, job=None):

        self.name = name
        self.job = job


class Account:

    _ID = 0

    def __init__(self, name, job=None):

        self.customer = Customer(name , "Customer")

    def __getattr__(self, attr):

            return getattr(self.customer, attr)
```

```
>>> A = Account("Abdi")
>>> A.__dict__
{'customer': <__main__.Customer object at 0x109fdbfc8>}
>>>
```

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do with `A.__dict__` ? `<__main__.Customer object at 0x109fdbfc8>` refers to the Customer instance you created for `self.customer` .

Comment: I want to display a dictionary of the instances for e.g. {customer {'name': "Abdi", 'job': "Manager",

Comment: @cyclopse87: this is what the `__repr__` and `__str__` class methods are for, to produce a human readable representation of a class instance.

Comment: Yes they are still learning thanks for the info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to implement the `__repr__` method to represent all of the  instances of the `Customer` class.

```
def __repr__(self): return repr(self.__dict__) # the dictionary of attributes in __repr__
```

Comment: According to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) return value of `__repr__` must be a string object.

Comment: Use `repr(self.__dict__)` not `str(...)` in the defintion of `__repr__`.